# Sed replace the first value

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace the first value (in first column and line so here 1) and add one to this value, so I  have a file like this

```
1
1 1
2 5
1 6
```

I use this sentence

```
read -r a < file
echo $aa
sed  "s/$aa/$(($aa + 1))/" file
# or 
sed  's/$aa/$(($aa + 1))/' file
```

But when I make that, he change all first column one into two. I have try to change the quote but it make nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

restrict the script to first line only, i.e.

```
sed '1s/old/new/'
```

awk might be a better tool for this.

```
awk 'NR==1{$1=$1+1}1'
```

for the first line add 1 to the first field and print.  Can be rewritten as

```
awk 'NR==1{$1+=1}1'
```

or

```
awk 'NR==1{$1++}1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -p0e 's/(\d+)/$1+1/e' file
```